# Optional argument in sh script

Tags: unix

I wonder if there is any way to execute script with argument that can be optional. 
For example

```
./script (optional parameter X) path
```

So typing `./script /Users/name/Documents` would execute certain function (I assume that if statement will be crucial) and `./script X Users/mcichecki/Documents` will execute another function.
I was trying to do it with optional arguments and it didn't work:

```
    ARG1=${1:-R}

    if [ "$1" = "X" ];
    then
        first_function
    else
        second_function
    fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the optional argument were last you could use default values. It doesn't work so well when it is first.

Use `$#` to check the number of arguments that were passed in.

```
case $# in
    1) ARG1=-R; ARG2=$1;;
    2) ARG1=$1; ARG2=$2;;

    *) echo "Usage: $0 [parameterX] path" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
```